# MySQL a real LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm helping a friend build a dictionary-of-sorts for a project he's working on. Part of the project is to create a Search functionality. The database is in MySQL, backend in php.

Now, running our simple query was a piece of cake:

```
 SELECT *,
    (
        (CASE WHEN word LIKE '%$query%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN defin LIKE '%$query%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS relev
    FROM dictionary
    WHERE word LIKE '%$q%'
    OR defin LIKE '%$q%'
    ORDER BY relev DESC;
```

It produced good results; for example, inputting "fire" gave us fire, firemen, firetruck, on fire, etc. However, we also want room for error: We want the mistake "prnk" to give us prank, prink and also pink, or the word "mule" to also suggest the word "mole".

Quite surprisingly, we weren't able to find any information on it. The relevence system is entirely superficial because we don't need actual relevence (just an overall pointer), but we do need something (and that's why we went for the LIKE statement and not the MATCH...AGAINST statement, where we found nowhere to sort by relevence.)

The database only consists of three things: id, word, defin. Simple as that, as that was the required complexity (or simplicity.)

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the SOUNDEX function - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex not something I've used but it might be what you're after

Comment: that's usually done with a spell check, php use pspell\enchant bot documented in the manual

Comment: also you should really be useing full text searching http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @Dagon - I tried using full text searches, but we couldn't figure out a way to also make a relativity system.

Comment: @Zirak you can, i could post some example code somewhere, i use it successfully.

Comment: SELECT url, author, title, body,
(
MATCH (body)
AGAINST ('$sql_search' ) 
)
AS relevance
FROM search
WHERE MATCH (title, body,author)
AGAINST ('$sql_search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
$sql_within
HAVING relevance >0
ORDER
BY relevance DESC

Comment: That is pretty awesome, however, how can you add variables to it? Using this method, fire won't match "firetruck" and gulf won't match "engulf". Still, your post is awesome, and deserves much more than a +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try testing if the word *sounds* like one in the dictionary, so something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *,
    (
        (CASE WHEN word LIKE '%$query%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN defin LIKE '%$query%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN LEFT(SOUNDEX(word), 4) = LEFT(SOUNDEX('$query'), 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
        (CASE WHEN LEFT(SOUNDEX(defin), 4) = LEFT(SOUNDEX('$query'), 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    ) AS relev
    FROM dictionary
    WHERE word LIKE '%$q%'
    OR defin LIKE '%$q%'
    ORDER BY relev DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked great; just added an extra two conditions with the SOUNDEX function, and Mule now also selects Mole.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding the prank...

http://webarto.com/80/did-you-mean-api

```
$q = "prnk"

$dym = new DYM;
$spell = $dym->check($q);
if(!empty($spell)){
    echo $spell; // prank
}
```

(not really API, not really reliable, but it's working in less than 0.5s)

For mule/mole part try finding Levenshtein implementation for SQL...

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php?&bw=1280#552 (link not working but Google it)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php

Comment: If I could select two answers, I would've selected yours too; but unfortunately I can't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try SOUNDS LIKE:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like

Comment: Would that retain the ability of appending and prepending things? Will searching "fire" also find "fireplace"?

Comment: no, you could try using   'a LIKE b OR a SOUNDS LIKE b' though.

Comment: Please note, that using SOUNDS LIKE will require full table scan each time.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Soundex (Sounds Like)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex) function in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Soundex and Levenshtein, you could also look into [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) or Double Metaphone, even though the latter ones doesn't have built-in support in MySQL. PHP supports it though, see [metaphone](http://php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php) - and there are a few double metaphone implementations floating around as well (ie. http://swoodbridge.com/DoubleMetaPhone/).